# Parsing CSV using OleDb using C# - Error column contain values with in double quotes those are not loaded in datatable

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, type-conversion

I am using OleDb to convert csv file as data table in c#.

I have problem with columns which has value having double quotes("),
in this case after double quotes values and remaining columns values are not loaded in datatable.

here this is my code,

private DataTable ReadFileByDataTable (string sFileName)
        {
                    DataTable dtPOFileData = new DataTable();

```
        using (OleDbConnection cnnOleDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Test;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'"))
        {
            cnnOleDB.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adpPOFileData = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["test.csv"]", cnnOleDB))
            {
                adpPOFileData.Fill(dtPOFileData);
            }
        }

        return dtPOFileData;
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: private DataTable ReadFileByDataTable (string sFileName) {
DataTable dtPOFileData = new DataTable();  using (OleDbConnection cnnOleDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Test;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'"))
        {
            cnnOleDB.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adpPOFileData = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["test.csv"]", cnnOleDB))
            {
                adpPOFileData.Fill(dtPOFileData);
            }
        }

        return dtPOFileData;
    }

Comment: I have tried this delimiter option and solve my problem  OleDbConnection cnnOleDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Test;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this delimiter option and solve my problem  OleDbConnection cnnOleDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Test;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';'"

here full version of the code,

private DataTable ReadFileByDataTable (string sFileName) {
DataTable dtPOFileData = new DataTable();

```
    using (OleDbConnection cnnOleDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Test;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';"))
    {
        cnnOleDB.Open();

        using (OleDbDataAdapter adpPOFileData = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["test.csv"]", cnnOleDB))
        {
            adpPOFileData.Fill(dtPOFileData);
        }
    }

    return dtPOFileData;
}
```